# Agora.io - React: How to allow audience join the stream only when host is in and remove them when host leaves

Tags: reactjs, typescript, agora.io

I'm working on integrating Agora for 1to1 communication in a react/ typescript web app.

I currently have a room / {uuid} route accessible to both the host and the public.

As for the entry of the audience, I can get around the problem as it is the host that must link the audience, but as regards the automatic exit of the audience when the call is closed, I tried to use the removeAllListeners method but the audience is not kicked out when the host stops the stream.

Which is the correct flow and the right methods to achieve this?
Thanks,

Federico

Answer (score 0):

Agora RTC SDK does not come with all the features necessary to implement this use case. You should use a WebSocket connection or use [Agora RTM SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/) to implement a data layer between the audience and the host.

Then you can signal from the host's side if and when a host joins a channel. This signal can be used on the audience's side to invoke the [join](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#join) method.

Similarly when the host leaves, the host can send out a signal to all the audience that the broadcast has ended. Then the audience can use this opportunity to [leave](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#leave) the channel.

In case a host disconnects abruptly due to network issue or closed tab without leaving, The RTM SDK will emit the appropriate [event](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/interfaces/rtmevents.rtmchannelevents.html#memberleft) on the audience side from which place the same logic can be handled.